# proper ways to reduce loading big hashtable

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications

i have a JavaScript app that contains big hashtable (1 megabyte). What's the proper way to load it to reduce loading time?

the hash table is this:

```
function unicodeTable (num) {
    // returns the unicode name of a given unicode num in decimal
var unicodedata =
{
0x0020:"SPACE",
// tens of thousand entries here
}
...
}
```

the app is a Unicode browser. When user hovers over a Unicode, it displays its name and codepoint.

PS I'd like the solution not involving some js lib. Thanks.

Addendum:
the page is here
http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_6_emoticons_list.html

this is the JavaScript
http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_popup.js

on desktop/laptop it's fine, but i noticed on a Blackberry tablet, it froze browser for 5 or so minutes. I'm not sure how to use ajax, or perhaps worker is the answer?

Comment: Have you considered an array? What loading times are we talking about? Do you need the entire table in memory at the same time or can you consider loading some of the data from the server when needed?

Comment: Is your table actually declared as a function-scoped variable as the snippet indicates? It will be allocated again whenever the function is called...

Comment: you have a table in the page with all the characters ? because if you do, then just add the name there as a title attribute, and if the hover tooltip is not enough, this function can retrieve the title from there and show it in a nicer way. but you avoid this object altogether

Comment: the page is here
http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_6_emoticons_list.html

this is the JavaScript
http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_popup.js on desktop/laptop it's fine, but i noticed on a Blackberry tablet, it froze browser for 5 or so minutes.

Comment: k, so you already have the names in the title, there's no reason to have that object at all. just retrieve the title from the hovered element and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Load it asynchronously, like using AJAX
- Use a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) if possible
- Define it in a scope that does not terminate. This avoids JS from creating and destroying it everytime.

  ```
  function foo(){
    //creating bar
    var bar = 'someValue';
    //using bar here
    //bar will be destroyed as soon as foo is done
  }
  ```

  But in this one, bar lives since it's outside foo:

  ```
  //creating bar
  var bar = 'someValue';

  function foo(){
    //using bar here
    //bar still lives after foo is done
  }
  ```
- Offload processing (search, accessing, traversal) to a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) or a simulated worker using timers.

Comment: moving the hashtable out of function solved the problem. I thought modern js compilers took care of that?

Answer (score 2):

first, make sure you compress the responses with gzip. that will save a lot of space since texts compress really well. Second, there is no need to have a hashtable. you can just have an array with the names at their correct location and when someone hovers the space element in the page, you go in this array at [20] and retrieve the name. as i see there, that will save 7 bytes per char. so a bit from here and a bit from there it can add up. but that's about all i can think of.